# Place line break at at every variable semicolon in smarty template

Tags: smarty

I have a smarty template that contains a variable in which data is loaded as one text string but the values are separated by semicolons.

```
<span>{$TEST.data}</span>
```

This generates one line in with example: 1; example: 2; example: 3; and so on.

Is there a way I can code in a line break at every semicolon in smarty?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not sure, but this would be easy in PHP: `str_replace(";", ";<br>", $TEST->data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you actually should prepare your data in PHP, you can do this within Smarty:

```
{$test.data|replace:";":"<br>"}
```

see the docs on the [replace modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl)